# Simulate write delay to SCSI disk on Linux machine

Tags: scsi

I am testing my application and want to observe behavior when I get delay in SCSI disk write on a linux machine (Fedora). I want to control the delay to control the test.

I am exploring FUSE as an option to achieve this, I googled and there seem to be options to introduce faults but couldn't find a solution to introduce delays.

Anyone used something in past to achieve this?

Comment: If the delay isn't really at the SCSI level, but for the block device, with a layer of indirection (device mapper) it should be doable with this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/delay.txt (then look for dm-delay on internet there's a lot of information available)

Comment: looks exactly like what I want.